# Match regex with no consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex ([link to the regexr.com with this pattern and examples](https://regexr.com/64re6))

```js
const reg = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+[/]?[\w\-._~:?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=./]+$/gm
```

And it matches this urls

```
https://google.com
http://www.cool.com.au
http://www.cool.com.au/ersdfs
http://www.cool.com.au/ersdfs?dfd=dfgd@s=1
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/asdasd/asdasdasd
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/////
```

And not matches this

```
http://www.cool.com:81/index.html asdasd
https:google.com
www.cool.com.au
```

Where can I add exception so it will not match urls like this `http://www.example.com/////` with consecutive `/` character?

I've tried to add `/{1}` and `(?!./)` but it's not working.

Comment: Replace `[/]?[\w\-._~:?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=./]+` with `(?:/[\w.~:?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.-]+)*`

Comment: Note that `http://www.example.com/////` is still a valid URI, so your efforts to un-match it might be counter-productive.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you, please, show the full example with replaced items?

Comment: For example, this is valid too: `http://www.example.com//1//2//3`.

Comment: @TomLord yep, I understand. I want it to be an invalid url

Comment: seems like it would be easier to do it in two checks....

Comment: @epascarello That's a great suggestion! Thank you! Maybe you know how can I check if there are a consecutive `/` character?

Comment: something like `"http://example.com///".match(/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/).*\/\//)` will fail if // is in a query string which is probably valid... wrote it quick so not sure if it is 100% correct

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/HTjPHH/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can amend your regex to

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+(?:\/[\w.~:?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.-]+)*\/?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HTjPHH/1).

That is, replace `[/]?[\w\-._~:?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=./]+` with `(?:\/[\w.~:?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.-]+)*\/?`. This pattern part will make sure the `/` char is always separated from another `/` with at least one char.

Also consider replacing `(?:\/[\w.~:?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.-]+)*` with `(?:\/[^\/]+)*` if you do not care about what chars you can have in between `/`s, `[^\/]` matches any char but `/`.